# TF246017 error migrating from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2014 (2008 compatibility) - TFS 2013

Tags: sql-server, tfs

We are currently using TFS 2013 -  Upgrade 2, connected to a SQL Server 2008 instance.  We are trying to upgrade the TFS databases to a SQL Server 2014 instance (new server) with the databases being in 2008 compatibility.  When trying the preview function of the TFSConfig RemapDBs command, we are getting the "TF246017 Team Foundation Server could not connect to the database" error.  Is it potentially because TFS 2013 - Upgrade 2 doesn't support SQL Server 2014, despite the database being in a 2008 compatibility mode?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it might be a license issue, depending on when the TFS server was installed.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/bharry/use-of-sql-2014-with-tfs-2013/

Answer (score 1):

> Is it potentially because TFS 2013 - Upgrade 2 doesn't support SQL Server 2014, despite the database being in a 2008 compatibility mode?

Shouldn't be. TFS 2013 Update 2 supports SQL Server 2014.  See
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=tfs-2013